# How to convert MS Access DB from version 97 to 93 (not a typo)

Tags: ms-access

How can I convert MS Access DB from verion 97 to 93?  Is this even possible?  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I'd like to take a full database (tables w/data, queries, forms and reports), but not the code.

Comment: This sounds totally crazy :-) Just do not try to go this way, if in any case possible...

Comment: Are you talking about just data or a full database with saved queries, forms, reports, code?

Comment: As far as I recall, the earlier versions of Access used their own code, Access VBA. In addition, there were a vast number of changes in the way objects were referenced, so I cannot see how forms and reports can be converted.

Comment: I am sorry too.  I'd like to take a full database (tables w/data, queries, forms and reports), but not the code.

Comment: Er, what is "93"? There is no such version of Access. Before 97, there was 95, 2, 1.1 and 1, and that's it. There was never any release called Access 93 (though Access 1 may have been released in 93).

Comment: There is no backward conversion for versions before 97. From Access 2 to 95, there was the huge change from Access Basic to VBA, and it wouldn't be possible to do the conversion (though I guess it could be done by hand -- might also be doable with the compatibility library that was usually used as a helper for the Access 2 to 95/97 conversion).

Comment: It occurs to me that Access Basic may have supported some form of SaveAsText, but after just checking in Access 2, I can't get anything to work with it. Surely there was a text method for loading forms back then, but a VBA form definition wouldn't be compatible with Access 2's Access Basic. Probably it would be just as fast to copy and paste code manually. Form and report design would be a pain, though. SQL should be exportable directly (or via Access 2).

Comment: thanks david.. if you post an answer here, i will deem it as the correct answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **won't** be able to use the following as Remou found the relevant sentence in the help.

```
DBEngine.CompactDatabase "olddb", "newdb", , dbVersion20
```

where dbversion11 could be dbversion10 for Access 1.0 and dbVersion11 could be for Access 1.1.

Now I just tried this in A97 on my own system and I doubt it worked.  When I opened up the "newdb" I didn't get any kind of message telling me I was opening an older version or offering to convert it for me.

I poked about in A97 and the help and couldn't find any means of backwords conversion.  So I suspect David is correct in that there was no going back.

**Edited** as per Remou's comment.

Comment: From 2000 Help "You can specify only one version constant. If you omit a version constant, newdb will have the same version as olddb. You can compact newdb only to a version that is the same or later than that of olddb."